# Code Igniter: Load controller with jQuery but forbid direct url loading

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have a website build in Code Igniter with a commenting system that loads a controller function with jQuery for each page.

I'm also passing the article ID as URI segment to the controller while loading.

Lets say the controller name is "comments" and the function is:

```
function get_comments(){
$article_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
echo 'the uri segment is '.$article_id;
}
```

I call them to my page with the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.comments-holder').load('<?php echo base_url();?>comments/get_comments/'<?php echo $article_id;?>);
});
```

and this is fine.

The thing I want to accomplish is to forbid the user to load the "get_comment" function by typing the `http://www.domain.com/comments/get_comments/`

I believe that is possible not to have a solution for this problem a workaround will work good as well even if it means more changes to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code igniter has this by default.

Add this in the ajax action:

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
    // your regular ajax code
} else {
    // redirect or show error
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you, I cannot beleive I missed it in the manual.